# jquery - how to take a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

let's say we have this html code :

```html
<tr>
 <td><a href="#depend"><i id="damage-file" class="fa fa-group">test1</i></a></td>
 <td><a href="#depend"><i id="damage-file" class="fa fa-group">test2</i></a></td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td><a href="#depend"><i id="damage-file" class="fa fa-group">test3</i></a></td>
 <td><a href="#depend"><i id="damage-file" class="fa fa-group">test4</i></a></td>

</tr>
```

every time i click on one of those link a jquery code get to run , here is the jquery :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //References
 var sections = $("i");
 var loading = $("#loading");
 var content = $("#ajax-box");
 var id = 2 // <= this should be the value of tr
 
 sections.click(function(){
  
  showLoading();
  
  switch(this.id){
   case "damage-file":
    content.slideToggle();
    content.load("./sections.php #section_home",{'userdata':id}, hideLoading);

    break;
   case "depend-people":
    content.slideToggle();
    content.load("./sections.php #section_people", hideLoading);
    break; 
   default:
    //hide loading bar if there is no selected section
    hideLoading();
    break;
  }
 });

 //show loading bar
 function showLoading(){
  loading
   .css({visibility:"visible"})
   .css({opacity:"1"})
   .css({display:"block"})
  ;
 }

 function hideLoading(){
  loading.fadeTo(1000, 0);
 };
});
```

(as you can see i use jquery to load another page)

every "tr" tag have a number and i want when i click on the any link (into a "tr") that number goes to the jquery >> "var id" .for exmaple this is a code :

```html
<tr id="123">
    <td><a href="#depend"><i id="damage-file" class="fa fa-group">test1</i></a></td>
  </tr>
<tr id="456">
    <td><a href="#depend"><i id="damage-file" class="fa fa-group">test2</i></a></td>
 </tr>
```

when i click on "test1" then id=123 should goes to the jquery as value and if i click on "test2" then id=456 goes to the jquery as a value..can somebody help me for this problem?

Comment: I think you might be running in to some problems here firstly because your HTML has some issues. You can only use a given ID once, so having multiple `id="damage-file"` won't work - you should change that to a data-attribute or a class. Next up, you're using numerical IDs for the TRs, in HTML, IDs can not start with a number, so once again, you could use a data-attribute to store that data, or change the IDs to be prefixed with a string.

Comment: @Dymos, with [HTML5 spec it allows an id to be anything as long as it doesn't contain spaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). Though if the OP is simply using the `id` attribute as a way to store that data then you are correct with the data-attribute suggestion.

Comment: @PatrickEvans oh thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realise they had changed that!

Comment: tnx for comment.. i know that but that's just a example i just want to get my point.. it's doesn't matter how we should write that .. i wanna know how it's possible or even is it possible or not ?

Comment: We cannot imagine what you have in mind, we can only help based on what you show. Also, the snippets you created should be placed in a _single_ snippet. As they are now they are pretty useless…

Answer (score 2):

You need to traverse up the DOM tree from the clicked element `<i>` until you get to your `<tr>`. Luckily [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) has a method for this called [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest). Simply pass it the selector that you want to match and it will get the closest parent element.

In your case since you want to get the parent `<tr>` it would look like

```
sections.click(function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
```